# How to handle mutiple async methods from running?

Tags: c#, asynchronous, windows-store-apps, winrt-xaml, winrt-async

How can i know if an async(awaitable) operation is already running and waiting for completion in the application. I have two buttons in a view each binded to two differrent async methods. If button1 is clicked and the async is started and waiting for its result. And at that time if the button2 is clicked. I need to show a message that an already running async methos is there and stop the second async method from executing. How can i achieve this?

Comment: Are the async operations you're running cancellable?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Store the task and check for `IsCompleted` Property.

```
private Task pendingTask = Task.FromResult(0);

private async void Button1Click()
{
    if (!pendingTask.IsCompleted)
    {
        //Notify the user
        return;
    }

    pendingTask = DoSomethingAsync();
    await pendingTask;
    ...
}

private async  void Button2Click()
{
    if (!pendingTask.IsCompleted)
    {
        //Notify the user
        return;
    }

    pendingTask = DoSomethingElseAsync();
    await pendingTask;
    ...
}
```

As noted by @Peter Ritchie in comments, better idea is to disable the other button when asynchronous operation is pending. You may consider using it.

Comment: disabling the button to start a task seems like a better idea; you can't click a button that's disabled.  If you can, the task is completed.

Comment: @PeterRitchie Yes very good idea. noob, consiser this as a better alternate.

Comment: I would like to show a message like "Already running" when the second button is clicked. If the button is disabled i wont be able to catch that event. The approach mentioned by sriram seems fine. Let me try out that first.

Answer (score 2):

`Task` class has a [`Status`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.threading.tasks.task.status%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) property which can be used to evaluate if an asynchronous operation is running or it has completed or even if it's in faulted state.

Answer (score 1):

You can store the executed `Task` inside your form and look up its `Status` property:

```
public class Form1
{
    private Task fooTask = Task.FromResult(0);

    public Task FooAsync()
    {
        return Task.FromResult(0);
    }

    public async void MyEventHandler(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        if (fooTask.Status == TaskStatus.Running)
        {
            // If we got here, the task is currently running. Notify someone
            return;
        }

        // If we're here, the task isn't running.
    }
}
```

Note this doesn't take care of situations where your task might be in a `Faulted` or `Canceled` state, which you may want to handle as well.